# Open port on one IP

Tags: iptables

I have spent all day looking this up with no luck.

So, I own the IP range `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/27` and I want to open port `22` on IP `xxx.xxx.xxx.66` yet close port `22` on all others, then open port `80`/`443`/`4567` on IP `xxx.xxx.xxx.90` and finally open port `25565` on ports `xxx.xxx.xxx.(70|80)`.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Mon Sep 14 07:23:06 2015
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [4:240]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [31:3004]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 

# Allow HTTP/HTTPS connections from anywhere (normal ports for websites and SSL)
-A INPUT -s xxx.xxx.xxx.90 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d xxx.xxx.xxx.90 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s xxx.xxx.xxx.90 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d xxx.xxx.xxx.90 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

# Lets allow some TS3 server ports, they'll be running on xxx.xxx.xxx.89
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 10011 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 10011 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 30033 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 30033 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p udp --dport 9987 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 9987 -j ACCEPT 

# Lets allow NodeBB to use this machine..
# Well run it on 45.35.58.66 as no one **should** be finding out this IP.
-A INPUT -s xxx.xxx.xxx.66 -p tcp --dport 4567 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -d xxx.xxx.xxx.66 -p tcp --dport 4567 -j ACCEPT 

# We're going to block icmp on all other IPs, but all it on our main IP.
-A INPUT -s 45.35.58.66 -p icmp -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p icmp -j REJECT 

# Drop all other inbound - default deny unless explicitly allowed policy
-A INPUT -j DROP
-A FORWARD -j DROP

COMMIT
```

All help is appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Are you working with `iptables` commands directly? What is your network topology? What interfaces are configured on your router, what are their IP addresses, and which one has the default route?

Comment: Hi,
I tried using this: http://paste.md-5.net/widunajala.vhdl, I'm currently using eth1 which has all my IPs from 66 to 94. Thanks.

Comment: Hi James! It would be best to post what you tried as an [edit] to your post, rather than a link.

Comment: I don't see how that makes any difference?
But ok..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Iptables**

You can use `iptables` using the following syntax

```
iptables -A INPUT -s [source IP] -p [protocol] --dport [destination port] -j [ACTION]
```

You need to **ACCEPT** the connection from the specific IP and then **DROP** it to all traffic.

E.g.

```
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -s XXX.XXXX.XXX.66 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
```

To get familiarized with `iptables` you can give a look in [here](http://rlworkman.net/howtos/iptables/iptables-tutorial.html)

Comment: @James J You're very welcome, if it really was what you where looking for please accept the answer to mark the question as solved